# react - how do I get the size of a component child elements and reposition them

Tags: reactjs

I have a component, which arranges elements in a dynamic grid, something like this:

```
class GridComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      {items.map(function(item){
          return <ItemComponent someData={item}/>;
      })}
    </div>
  }
}
```

Now I want to position the `ItemComponents` based on some algorithm, which needs the individual `ItemComponents`dimensions.

So I guess, I need to:

1. Render all `ItemComponents`
2. Get the dimensions of all `ItemComponents` (which are only fixed after they have been rendered)
3. Reposition the `ItemComponents` based on my algorithm

So my question is how to this, or more specific:

- How do I execute some code when all `ItemComponents` have been rendered?
- How do I get the dimensions of the `ItemComponents` from within GridComponent?
- Should I then rerender the `GridComponent` with the calculated `ItemComponents` position or should I set the positions of the `ItemComponents` somehow directly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a pretty cool idea and you can totally do this using internal state and a few React lifecycle methods. To answer each of your questions:

- the function `componentDidMount` will get called on the parent after all constructors and `componentDidMount` of every child, therefore here is a good place to call some function that maybe relies on your state
- by dimensions I assume you mean the screen width and height of the root component of `ItemComponent`s therefore on `componentDidMount` in `ItemComponent`, you can set a `ref` and find the width and height of the DOM element
- the best solution would be to mount but not render the children (can be done with some initialization state variable or prop) and only render them once you've calculated their true final positions. For example, each `ItemComponent` can have a prop called `initialized` which is false until the parent finds where to place it.

Putting all of these together, since your algorithm will likely need all dimensions to work, you'll likely want to create a callback in your parent, let's call it `setItemDimensions(id, width, height)`, which gets called on `componentDidMount` of each `ItemComponent`. You should be keeping a map of all your initialized `ItemComponent`s and every time the `setItemDimensions` is called, check to see if there are any remaining (maybe initialize the map with all nulls and assume it's "ready" when there are no nulls left).

Once the last `null` is gone, you can run the algorithm, figure out the positions, and render the `ItemComponent`s in the right place and with `initialized={true}` (or just `initialized`).

Let's see if that works!

Comment: Cool, I will try this! What is the best way to mount but not render a component? Just setting "display:none"?

Comment: @Nathan return null

Comment: @JamesBrierley OK ... but then it will of no size/dimensions which I can use for my calculation ...

Comment: yeah if you want to measure the elements, then you MUST render them.  There's no way around it.

Comment: you can also do `opacity: 0`