# React: Get element size in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-ref

I'm trying to implement [the solution provided in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37924214/2521204)

In the second step, I need to get the size of a `div` defined in my component in my component's componentDidMount. Many threads on StackOverflow have proposed using [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-to-dom-components) for this purpose. However, I have difficulty understanding how to implement it. Would you please give me a piece of code as an example to learn how to get the element's size after it is mounted in componentDidMount?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a ref with [`createRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactcreateref) and store it in an instance variable which you pass to the `ref` prop of the element you want a reference to.

This ref will then have a reference to the node in the `current` property after the component has mounted.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  ref = React.createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    const { current } = this.ref;
    console.log(`${current.offsetWidth}, ${current.offsetHeight}`);
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={this.ref} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

By creating a ref you have access to all element's properties like offsetWidth.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element

```js
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
     items: [
       { text: "Learn JavaScript" },
        { text: "Learn React" },
        { text: "Play around in JSFiddle" },
        { text: "Build something awesome" }
      ]
    }
    
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
   console.log(this.myRef.current.offsetWidth);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.myRef}>
        {this.state.items.map((item, key) => (
          <div className="rootContainer" key={key}>
              <div className="item">{item.text}</div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.rootContainer {
  display: inline-block;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```